# erro javascript Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

Criei uma função em javascript, porem me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

Segue um pedaço do código:

```
function Distribuir(control) {
            var tr = $(control).parents('tr');

            var quantidade = $(tr).find("input[id*='txtQuantidade']").val();
            var distribuir = document.getElementById("txtDistribuir").value;
            if (document.getElementById("<%= txtDistribuir.ClientID %>") != null) {
                var distribuir = document.getElementById("txtDistribuir").value;
                resultado = distribuir - quantidade;
                $(tr).find("input[id*='txtDisponivel']").text(resultado);
            }
        }
```

ja estou fazendo o tratamento para ver se ele é nulo,  porém mesmo assim ele retorna o erro. na parte `var distribuir = document.getElementById("txtDistribuir").value` está sempre vindo undefined, nao consigo pegar o valor que está nesse textbox.

Comment: Pode postar a porção HTML da página?

Comment: são varios inputs, sabe como faria para pegar o valor de varios e soma-los?

Comment: Se apanha "Cannot read property 'value' of null" nessa linha é porque o `id` não existe. Se o html é gerado por JSP que é o que parece pela sintaxe, aconselho a visualizar o código fonte gerado na página, pois pode ser diferente daquele que imagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa continuar utilizando o ClientID dentro do 'If'.
Existe uma diferença entre

```
document.getElementById("txtDistribuir")
document.getElementById("<%= txtDistribuir.ClientID %>"
```

O primeiro busca exatamente a string "txtDistribuir" na página, enquanto o segundo busca uma string gerada dinamicamente pelo Web Forms.

Tente o seguinte:

```
   function Distribuir(control) {
        var tr = $(control).parents('tr');

        var quantidade = $(tr).find("input[id*='txtQuantidade']").val();
        var distribuir = document.getElementById("txtDistribuir").value;
        if (document.getElementById("<%= txtDistribuir.ClientID %>") != null) {
            var distribuir = document.getElementById("<%= txtDistribuir.ClientID %>").value;
            resultado = distribuir - quantidade;
            $(tr).find("input[id*='txtDisponivel']").text(resultado);
        }
    }
```